# how to Customize Link Rendering type with HAL in Grails?

Tags: rest, grails, hateoas, hal-json

From the Customizing Link Rendering section in grails documentation, I can see
it is possible to customize the href

```
book.link rel:'publisher', href: g.link(resource:"publisher", params:[bookId: book.id])
```

How do I customize the 'type' field?

Comment: Most of the grails tags simply "pass though" any attributes they don't know about. So you can add attributes like `class`. I haven't tried a `type` attribute but it should work.... Have you tried it?

Comment: yes I tried `user.link(rel:'new', href: "http://google.com", type: 'application/json')` the `rel` and `href` work, the type has no effect?